# <console>:40: error: value join is not a member of Unit

Tags: apache-spark

Need your help with subjected error

following code is executing and  getting error

```
scala> val join = bat_first_won.join(total_matches_per_venue).map(x=>(x._1,(x._2._1*100/x._2._2))).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false).collect.foreach(println)
<console>:40: error: value join is not a member of Unit
val join = bat_first_won.join(total_matches_per_venue).map(x=>(x._1,(x._2._1*100/x._2._2))).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false).collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Your `bat_first_won` is a `Unit`, not the `RDD` you expected. You need to look at how you derived that. It would help us to see that too,

Comment: Vidya is correct.  Also you are assigning `val join` to the result of a call to `foreach`, which will be of type `Unit`. Is it possible you have done something similar when assigning `bat_first_won`? Did you mean something like `val join = bat_first_won.join(total_matches_per_venue).map(x=>(x._1,(x._2._1*100/x._2._2))).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false) /*new line*/  join.collect.foreach(println)`

Comment: Thanks Guys for your help so far...complete set of codes as follows

Comment: val data = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/matches.csv")
val filtering_bad_records = data.map(line=>line.split(",")).filter(x=>x.length<19)
val extracting_columns = filtering_bad_records.map(x=>(x(7),x(11),x(12),x(14)))
val bat_first_won = extracting_columns.filter(x=>x._2!="0").map(x=>(x._4,1)) .reduceByKey(_+_).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false).collect.foreach(println)
val total_matches_per_venue = filtering_bad_records.map(x=>(x(14),1)).reduceByKey(_+_).map(item => item.swap).sortByKey(false).collect.foreach(println)

Answer (score 0):

If you use collect at end of the line, the output is an Array. So remove from collect and try to execute the line, then it is a RDD. Then you can apply join operation onRDD